# how prove there are infinite numbers $\frac{a_{i}}{1234}\in N$ and $a_{n+2}=a^2_{n+1}-a_{n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory

let $a_{1}=287,a_{2}=39$,and

> $$a_{n+2}=a^2_{n+1}-a_{n}$$
>   show that: this sequence $\{a_{n}\}$ contains infinitely many $a_{i}$,such that $\dfrac{a_{i}}{1234}\in N$

My try:

> since
>   $$a_{3}=a^2_{2}-a_{1}=39^2-287=1234$$
>   so
>   $$\dfrac{a_{3}}{1234}=1$$
>   so $a_{3}$ is such

and
$$a_{4}=a^2_{3}-a_{2}=1234^2-39=1522717$$
and $\dfrac{a_{4}}{1234}\notin Z$
so $a_{4}$ is not such

> $$a_{5}=a^2_{4}-a_{3}=1522717^2-1234$$
>   and
>   $$\dfrac{a_{5}}{1234}=1878984652$$
>   so $a_{5}$ is such condition

$\cdots\cdots$

and How prove there are infinite $a_{i}$ such $\dfrac{a_{i}}{1234}\in N?$

Thank you

Comment: Consider the sequence of remainders modulo $1234$. Brute force tells you it has a period of $810$.

Comment: Your base cases are enough to suggest you perform an induction to show that $a_k$ divisible by 1234 $\Rightarrow$ $a_{k+2}$ is divisible by 1234.

Comment: @zibadawatimmy,why? can you post your solution?

Comment: @chinamath Well, just look at his post.  He computed that $a_1,a_3,a_5$ are divisible by 1234.  That suggests every odd-index term is divisible by 1234.

Comment: I mean how induction? Thank you

Comment: Same way you do every other induction: by playing around with it until something sticks.  I'd start by noticing the defining relation would give an equivalent problem of showing "1234 divides $a_k$ $\Rightarrow$ 1234 divides $a_{k+1}^2$.  Whether this gets you anywhere is something to see for yourself.

Comment: $a_5$ is **not** divisible by $1234$. In fact, $1522717^2-1234 = 2318667060855 = 1878984652\cdot 1234 +287$.

Comment: @DanielFischer Ah, okay, I just trusted the original poster had done the calculation correctly.  That explains why your period of 810 thing doesn't jive with his numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a standard problem.

Consider the pairs of numbers $ (a_i, a_{i+1})$ taken modulo 1234. In the first $1234 \times 1234 + 1 $ pairs, there must be 2 which are identically the same by the Pigeonhole Principle. Let's say that $(a_I, a_{I+1}) \equiv (a_{I+k} , a_{I+k+1}) $ for some $I, k$.

Claim: For all $n \geq 0$, $a_{I+n} \equiv a_{I+k+n} \pmod{1234}$.
This is obvious by from the recurrence relation $a_{n+2} = a_{n+1}^2 - a_n$.

Claim: For all $n\leq 0$, $a_{I +n} \equiv a_{I+k+n} \pmod{1234}$.
This is obvious by induction on the recurrence relation $a_n = a_{n+1}^2 - a_{n+2}$.

Hence, the sequence $a_i$ taken modulo 1234 is (immediately) periodic, with a period of $k$.

As calculated, $a_3 \equiv 0 \pmod{1234}$. Thus, there are infinitely many numbers which are multiples of 1234.

Note: Daniel points out that the period is 810. (Don't ask me what the period is.)